# Get-ChildItem -Path Getting Current Directory

Tags: powershell

I have a simple task of getting a file from one path and copying it to another using PowerShell script. Now, I understand that using `Get-ChildItem`, if`-Path` is not specified, it will get the current directory. I'm using this code, setting the directory the file is in, but it is still getting the current directory:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT\Files\STC" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1
Copy-Item $file -Destination "\\Brhnx3kfs01.vcp.amer.dell.com\brh_shipping$\DEMAND_MONITOR\"
cmd /c pause | out-null
```

It returns this error when it pauses:

[image]

This is script follow the rules in the documentation of both [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) and [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6). Am I missing something? Why is it still getting the current directory? I tried mutiple syntaxes differences, getting the paths out of commas, not setting -Path or -Destination, setting the file directly in the Copy-Item without using the `$file` variable...

Comment: `Copy-Item $file ...` -> `$file |Copy-Item ...` or `Copy-Item $file.FullName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Copy-Item` expects a `[string]` as the first positional argument - so it attempts to convert `$file` to a string, which results in the *name* of the file.

Either reference the `FullName` property value (the full path) of the file:

```
Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination "\\Brhnx3kfs01.vcp.amer.dell.com\brh_shipping$\DEMAND_MONITOR\"
```

Or pipe the `$file` object to `Copy-Item` and let pipeline binding do its magic for you:

```
$file |Copy-Item -Destination "\\Brhnx3kfs01.vcp.amer.dell.com\brh_shipping$\DEMAND_MONITOR\"
```

If you want to see for yourself how this is processed internally by powershell for yourself, use `Trace-Command`:

```
Trace-Command -Name ParameterBinding -Expression {Copy-Item $file -Destination "\\Brhnx3kfs01.vcp.amer.dell.com\brh_shipping$\DEMAND_MONITOR\"} -PSHost
```